# Spectral radius of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}A^{11} & \mathbf{0} 
\\ \mathbf{0} & A^{22} \end{bmatrix}$ be a square block matrix where $A^{ii} \in R^{m_i \times m_i}$ ($i=1,2$) and $Q = \begin{bmatrix}Q^{11} & Q^{12} 
\\ Q^{21} & Q^{22} \end{bmatrix}$ be another square block matrix with the same shape as $A$ ($Q^{ii} \in R^{m_i \times m_i}$). We assume that $Q$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Now, if we know that there exists a matrix $H$ (with the same shape as $A$ and $Q$) such that spectral radius of $A + HQ$ is less than 1 (which means maximum of absolute eigen-values of $A + HQ$ is less than 1), what can we say about the existence of a matrix $H^i$ (with the same shape as $A^{ii}$ and $Q^{ii}$) such that spectral radius of $A^{ii} + H^iQ^{ii}$ is less than 1? In other words, is there any matrix $H^i$ such that spectral radius of $A^{ii} + H^iQ^{ii}$ is less than 1?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but perhaps may be of some use.

Let $N$ be the null space of $Q$.  Then $HQ$ can be any $(m_1+m_2)\times (m_1+m_2)$ matrix whose null space contains $N$.  Namely, given such a matrix $B$, noting that the restriction $Q_{N^\perp}$ of $Q$ to the orthogonal complement $N^\perp$ of $N$ is invertible, we define
$H v = 0$ for $v \in N$ and $H v = B Q_{N^\perp}^{-1} v$ for $v \in N^\perp$.

Thus the statement that there is $H$ such that the spectral radius of $A+HQ$ is less than $1$ means just that there is a matrix $B$ of spectral radius $<1$ such that $Bv = Av$ for $v \in N$.  Of course this would not be true if $A$ has an eigenvector in $N$ with eigenvalue of absolute value $\ge 1$. 
Somewhat more generally, it would not be true if there exist $\epsilon > 0$ and a  vector $v \in N$ such that for all positive integers $j$, $A^j v \in N$ and  $\|A^j v\| > \epsilon$.  I don't know if that is an "if and only if".

Comment: I am not sure if I got the last few lines of your answer. You are saying it might not be true that "there exists ..."?

Comment: I'm saying if such $\epsilon$ and $v$ exist, there is no $H$ such that the spectral radius of $A+HQ$ is less than $1$.  So if such an $H$ does exist, there are no such $\epsilon$ and $v$.